# RabbitMQ Consumer throwing error when using priority

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am trying to switch my task queue to utilize priority support, I was able to set the x-max-priority value creating the task, but when I try to fetch a task, it is throwing an error.

Is there a special way to fetch the task using a consumer?

```
$channel->queue_declare('task_queue', false, true, false, false);
```

> PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPProtocolChannelException' with message
>   'PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue
>   'task_queue' in vhost 'vhost': received none but current is the value
>   '100' of type 'signedint'' in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php:188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `$channel->queue_declare` with identical parameters on both sides.

So you must set the priority property on both sides like

```
$channel->queue_declare('task_queue', false, true, false, false, false, $parameters);
```

where `$parameters` is an array declared like

```
$parameters = [
    'x-max-priority' => ['I', 100],
];
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to declare it with this: 
        $parameters['x-max-priority'] = array('I', 100);

        $channel->queue_declare('task_queue', false, true, false, false, false, $parameters);

Comment: I tried to insert 500k tasks using the priority (set randomly between 1-100), and I noticed after 200-300k tasks, it became very slow (240/s), does RabbitMQ have to sort/index these?

Comment: @Kevin I know that the rabbitmq has overhead of the prioritised queues, but none of my workloads has a use case of having a such a large spikes of unconsumed messages at once. So I don't know